# Pig Not Making Any Progress

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I just wrote my first pig script, it does not seem to be making any progress.  Some background info:

I'm running CDH4.5 on a CentOS 6.4 VM, all installed from Cloudera's yum repo.  It is configured to all run in pseudo-distributed mode.  Everything is running as a service and appears to be configured correctly (thank heaven!)

Here is my pig script:

```
A = LOAD '/user/msknapp/county_insurance_pp.txt' AS (fips:int,st:chararray,stfips:int,name:chararray,a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int,e:int,f:int,g:int);
DUMP A;
```

The input file was taken from data.gov, it's some insurance data.  I pre-processed it, here is some useful info:

```
[msknapp@localhost data]$ cat county_insurance_pp.txt | grep BUTLER
1013    AL  1   BUTLER  54480   129         3287        57895
19023   IA  19  BUTLER  27291   29659           3386    25150   85486
20015   KS  20  BUTLER  233855  10028       456 29278   5759    279376
21031   KY  21  BUTLER  4164                453     4617
29023   MO  29  BUTLER  48240   5217        738 2042    25081   81317
31023   NE  31  BUTLER  4406            153 609     5168
39017   OH  39  BUTLER  856205  103041  3854    38648   203328  19832   1224910
42019   PA  42  BUTLER  1072941 19131   190 60648   68692   50230   1271832
[msknapp@localhost data]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/msknapp/county_insurance_pp.txt | head 
1001    AL  1   AUTAUGA 215624  37156   46  130 53237   140420  446614
1003    AL  1   BALDWIN 1060297 95925   3284    31096   99241   200581  1490424
1005    AL  1   BARBOUR 37893   132     246 811     39082
1007    AL  1   BIBB    3127    70      241 34403       37841
1009    AL  1   BLOUNT  32311       135 11884   19392   4200    67922
1011    AL  1   BULLOCK 4301    336     274 186     5098
1013    AL  1   BUTLER  54480   129         3287        57895
1015    AL  1   CALHOUN 469959  92702   5373    2130    17069   532033  1119265
1017    AL  1   CHAMBERS    37238   3189        292 1953        42672
1019    AL  1   CHEROKEE    37984   190 117 1081    1277        40649
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

When I run the pig script on the command line I get a whole bunch of log statements and it looks like it is running, but once it starts, it never makes any progress, no matter how long I wait.  These are the last couple lines:

```
2014-01-05 15:10:41,113 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_1388936205793_0006
2014-01-05 15:10:41,511 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl - Submitted application application_1388936205793_0006 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2014-01-05 15:10:41,564 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1388936205793_0006/
2014-01-05 15:10:41,653 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
```

I modified the pig script to point to my local filesystem file, and ran the pig script in local mode, and the job finished successfully in seconds.  The local copy of the file is identical to the one hdfs has.  I think for some reason pig can't make a solid connection to my HDFS.

Would somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the job in the monitoring page? There may be some clues there. The page url is in your log, like `2014-01-05 15:10:41,564 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1388936205793_0006/`

Comment: When I go to that page it says "The requested application does not appear to be running yet, and has not set a tracking URL."  No matter how long I wait it still says that.

Comment: That means Pig can not commit the MapReduce jobs. Can you check the pig log?

Comment: the pig log does not exist.  I installed pig using an RPM from cloudera, there is no log directory dedicated to pig.  The console output says it's logging error messages to /home/msknapp/data/pig_1288978317277.log, and that file does not exist.  In the past when I have had errors, that log file was created, but right now it's not being created.  I checked in about six different hadoop logs and did not see any errors.

Comment: could this be a permission problem on my local file system?  I understand that pig makes a custom jar for M/R, but I don't know where it is trying to store that.  It's certainly not in the directory I'm running the app from, the logs say it built Job3010454826775377909.jar, but I can't find it.  Perhaps that file is created with wrong permissions, or put in a directory that my user can't write to.  Do you know where Pig tries to write that jar to?  And what permissions it assigns to it?

Comment: I found out that the jar it creates is going in my local file system's /tmp directory with permissions 664, as my user.  I think that should work, so I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: I think maybe Pig 0.11 is not compatible with the hadoop 2.0.0 that I am using.  I have tried almost everything except different versions of hadoop/pig

Comment: You installed Pig by yourself, not from Cloudera? You need to install Pig `0.11.0-cdh4.5.0` which has been well tested by Cloudera.

Comment: no, I installed pig from cloudera's yum repo.  However, CDH4.5 gives people the option of using hadoop 1 or hadoop 2, and either way they count this as CDH4.5.  In most of their instructions they have steps for YARN based hadoop (2+) and non-YARN hadoop.  Cloudera's pig instructions never mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
    A = LOAD '/user/msknapp/county_insurance_pp.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (fips:int,st:chararray,stfips:int,name:chararray,a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int,e:int,f:int,g:int);
    DUMP A;
```